# fabric(2.5) keeps asking for password using SSH connection

Tags: python, ssh, upgrade, fabric, autodeploy

I have upgraded fabric from `fabric3==1.14.post1` to `fabric=2.5.0`. Code works fine with `fabric3==1.14.post1`.
And now i have a problem while executing tasks inner another tasks.
The problem is that, when i run task, task must update and install soft in remote server which connects without password(with public key, don't ask password!).
Old version(1.14.post1):

```
from fabric.api import task, sudo, env, run

@task
def install_docker():
    sudo('apt-get update && apt-get install -qy docker.io')

@task
def task_queue():
    execute(install_docker)
    execute(install_some_soft)
```

How I run it: `fab task_queue`

New version(2.5.0)

```
@task
def install_docker(ctx):
    ctx.sudo('apt-get update && apt-get install -qy docker.io')

@task(pre=[install_docker])
def task_queue(ctx):
    pass
```

How I run it: `fab task-queue`
And i'm hiving error like this:

`invoke.exceptions.AuthFailure: The password submitted to prompt '[sudo] password: ' was rejected.`

Answer (score 0):

Use `--prompt-for-sudo-password` when you run `fab`.